# Importing qt application with visual studio-link error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt4

I used to build a Qt application with qmake using command prompt on visual studio 2010. But, I have recently installed Qt Visual Studio add-in and have imported a qt application from .pro file on visual studio, in order to be able to programm with IDE.

However, when I try to build the application, I get the following message:

> MSVCRTD.lib(crtexew.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol WinMain referenced in function __tmainCRTStartup

I know it has been said that this is a matter of choosing Windows (`/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS`) or Console (`/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE`) in the linker property of the project. However, neither option solves the problem. My Qt application uses GUI and also conole (I set `CONFIG += console` in .pro file).

I would appreciate if you could give me a suggestion to solve this issue.

Thanks a lot,

Daisuke

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. I just needed to get rid of Windows::... additional option in "Linker"-"Command Line" and choose console in "Linker"-"System"

Comment: Yep and whenever you launch your application it will have console launched... I gues it's not what you want for GUI app